# Navigation drawer unlock mode ignored

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, navigation-drawer

So I have this app with one activity (`MainActivity`) and I'm using the navigation architecture component. So it has `DrawerLayout` which is wrapping the `fragment` view.

These are two methods in the Activity class which are responsible for Locking and Unlocking of the `drawerLayout`.

```
...

fun lockNavDrawer() {
    drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)
}

fun unLockNavDrawer() {
    drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED)
}

...
```

There are some `fragments` which need to have the navigation drawer. Everything is working fine except those fragments which not suppose to have the `Drawer`.

So, in my base fragment, and I'm implementing an interface (`HasToolbar`) which have a variable called `hasNavigationDrawer` and in the `onDestroyView` of the base fragment, I'm doing this. The locking of the Drawer is fine.

```
if (this is HasToolbar) {
    if (hasNavigationDrawer) {
       activity.lockNavDrawer()
    }
    unregisterListeners()
}
```

But when I do this in the `onViewCreated` of the base fragment

```
if (this is HasToolbar) {
    if (hasNavigationDrawer) {
       activity.unlockNavDrawer()
    }
}
```

It does not unlock the drawer hence it does not open the drawer inside the fragment which suppose to have the drawer.

If I do this inside a `fragment` it works it stays unlocked.

```
lockNavDrawer()
unLockNavDrawer()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the ordering of the callbacks, you'll see that the `onViewCreated()` of the new Fragment is called *before* the `onDestroyView()` of the old Fragment. This makes particular sense when it comes to animations since to smoothly animate between two Fragments, both the new View and the old View must coexist and only after the animation ends does the old Fragment get destroyed. Fragments, in order to be consistent, use the same ordering whether you have an animation or not.

Ideally, your Fragments shouldn't be reaching up to the Activity at all to affect the Activity's behavior. As per the [Listen for Navigation Events documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#listen_for_navigation_events), you should instead use an `OnDestinationChangedListener` to update your Activity's UI. The listener only receives information about the destination and its arguments however, so to use this approach you'd want to add an argument to your navigation graph:

```
<!-- this destination leaves the drawer in its default unlocked state -->
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/fragment_with_drawer"
  android:name=".MainFragment" />
<!-- the drawer is locked when you're at this destination -->
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/fragment_with_locked_drawer"
  android:name=".SettingsFragment">
  <argument
    android:name="lock_drawer"
    android:defaultValue="true"/>
</fragment>
```

Then your `OnDestinationChangedListener` could look like

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, _, arguments ->
  if(arguments?.getBoolean("lock_drawer", false) == true) {
    lockNavDrawer()
  } else {
    unlockNavDrawer()
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! I really didn't know about those fragment things you told me.

Comment: Can you tell me this? 
How to clear the whole backstack of the nav controller?

Comment: As per the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination), you shouldn't be popping your start destination off the back stack, but you can certainly pop multiple destinations off the back stack with `popBackStack()` or `popUpTo`.