# Hide TabLayout and Toolbar in some Fragments / Handling onPause/onResume correctly

Tags: android, toolbar, android-tablayout, lifecycle

I am using a single Activity approach with a Navigation Graph. 
I don't want my tab layout or the toolbar visible in some fragments. I wrote a superclass to extend from in those fragments i don't want the bars. But somehow i do not understand the lifecycle correctly as this is not working:

```
 public class NoTabLayoutFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        hideTabLayout();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        showTabLayout();
    }

    private void showTabLayout() {
        if (getActivity() != null && getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_main_tab_layout) != null) {
            getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_main_tab_layout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }

    private void hideTabLayout() {
        if (getActivity() != null && getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_main_tab_layout) != null) {
            getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_main_tab_layout).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }
}
```

and

```
public class NoBarsFragment extends NoTabLayoutFragment {
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        hideToolbar();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        showToolbar();
    }

    private void hideToolbar() {
        if (getActivity() != null && ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }
    }

    private void showToolbar() {
        if (getActivity() != null && ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
        }
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Listen for Navigation Events documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#listen_for_navigation_events), the correct way to change UI visibility is via an `OnDestinationChangedListener`:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller,
           @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
       if(destination.getId() == R.id.full_screen_destination) {
           getSupportActionBar().hide()
       } else {
           getSupportActionBar().show()
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: You can also look at the [argument based listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57928305/1676363) if you want a technique that you can apply to many destinations without hard coding all of the ids in your activity's logic.

Comment: Hi @ianhanniballake , I came here from another question you marked as duplicated, this has solved my problem for hiding my appbar, but I have a little thing, there is an animation when transitioning from one fragment to the one I need to hide my appbar, that is not currently what Im specting, is this a normal behaviour for this library ? Because it folds up to disapear, is like that the transition, and also, is there a way to setup the toolbar I have in that fragment as the new appbar so I can put the homeNavigation arrow to that toolbar. Thanks

Comment: I cant use `(requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` in my new fragment to setup that toolbar because I'm getting this error **This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.** @ianhanniballake

Comment: @CoffeeBreak - the code here doesn't call `setSupportActionBar()`, nor is that required unless you're using a `NoActionBar` theme.

Comment: but in this case, if I use a NoActionBar theme I will need to add the toolbar to my main activity and propagate all the toolbar setup in each fragment I'm right ? Is there not an easy way to setup toolbars in different fragments without needing to redo all again ?

Comment: @CoffeeBreak - Using a theme that provides an action bar is totally fine if that's all you need. The alternatives (setting a Toolbar as your action bar in your activity or using separate Toolbars in each fragment) are only necessary if you actually need that functionality.

Comment: Yes, I need in one fragment show a collapsabletoolbar and in other a normal toolbar, I managed to add a toolbar to share in all fragments, but now I'm struggling to just include one collapsabletoolbar in one fragment and not in others, also there is an animation when hidding the actual toolbar when navigating which I think comes from the library itself

Comment: @CoffeeBreak - the animation is how the ActionBar's `hide()` and `show()` APIs work (it has nothing to do with Navigation).

Comment: but there is an option to disable that animation and just not show the actionbar at the destinatiojn ? @ianhanniballake

Comment: @CoffeeBreak - you can just not use the action bar. Toolbar works just fine on its own and `setVisibility(View.GONE)` has no animation associated with it.

Comment: you know, I have used the toolbar and the visibility to gone, but instead of the animation, it hides the toolbar, and lags to go to the other fragment, its like , I can see the toolbar dissapear before navigating and some weird animation happens

Answer (score 1):

I choose another approach:

Create:

```
public interface HideBehaviourListener {

onHide();
onRestore();

}
```

```
public interface ToolbarHideListener extends HideBehaviourListener {

}
```

```
public interface TabLayoutHideListener extends HideBehaviourListener {

}
```

Now, in your Fragment will add:

```
public class SomeFragment {

private ToolbarHideListener toolbarListener;
private TabLayoutHideListener tabLayoutListener;

@Override
public void onAttach(final Context context) {
super.onAttach(context);
toolbarListener = (ToolbarHideListener) context;
tabLayoutListener = (TabLayoutHideListener) context;
}

public void onResume() {
toolbarListener.onHide();
tabLayoutListener.onHide();
}

public void onPause() {
toolbarListener.onRestore();
tabLayoutListener.onRestore();
}
}
```

So... In your Activity need implement that interfaces with your logic. With this approach your Fragments do not know any resources or behaviour of Activity.

Comment: I will try this. I wonder if this solves my issue with the onPause and onResume

Comment: Ended up using the official approach

Comment: Ok, dont worry, but think about this communication is the official by Google: Communication between Activity and Fragment:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

Regards!