# Adding Default Navigation Drawer to NewActivity

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I Created a new project with default Drawer in 3.5.1 version.
I am creating new Activity(ProfileActivity), I want MainActivity's Drawer here too.

It's opening HomeFragment when I try to open ProfileActivity from navigation drawer. Yes I have given right id.

Trying to make it done for months but it's not happening, this time may give up. everywhere they give solution about fragment.

I tried in

ProfileActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_profile, null, false);
        final TextView textView = contentView.findViewById( R.id.text_gallery );
        drawer.addView(contentView, 0);
    }
}
```

and made drawer protected

It's opening HomeFragment when I try to open ProfileActivity from navigation drawer. Yes I have given right id

```
<item
            android:id="@+id/profileActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Profile" />
```

My MainActivity is as following

```
package com.example.iqhut;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import android.view.View;

import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    protected DrawerLayout drawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById( R.id.toolbar );
        setSupportActionBar( toolbar );
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById( R.id.fab );
        fab.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make( view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG )
                        .setAction( "Action", null ).show();
            }
        } );
        drawer = findViewById( R.id.drawer_layout );
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById( R.id.nav_view );
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send, R.id.profileActivity )
                .setDrawerLayout( drawer )
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController( this, R.id.nav_host_fragment );
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController( this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration );
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController( navigationView, navController );

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.main, menu );
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController( this, R.id.nav_host_fragment );
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp( navController, mAppBarConfiguration )
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

Comment: your question is really not clear man. please could you explain more?

Comment: @AlanDeep in Navigation Drawer when I click on activity(ProfileActivity) it opens the first fragment(HomeFragment).

Comment: why you're not setting content view in profileActivity?

Comment: @AlanDeep how should I do that, Sorry Really new to android.

Comment: Can you include your navigation XML file?

Comment: `setContentView()` after `super.onCreate()`

Comment: @AlanDeep I just tried it, it's opening new page but navigation drawer is not showing. There should be Navigation Drawer.
Code is : setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

Comment: you want the same navigation drawer in both activities? in MainActivity it's visible but ProfileActivity it's not visible? Did I get you right?

Comment: Yes Brother 100% correct

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the DrawerLayout, there is no reason to use a separate activity. Instead, you can [listen for navigation events](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#listen_for_navigation_events) and disable the DrawerLayout when on your profile destination:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller,
           @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
       if(destination.getId() == R.id.profileFragment) {
           drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
       } else {
           drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57928305/1676363) about using an argument based `OnDestinationChangedListener` if you need to lock the drawer on multiple destinations.

Comment: You don't need a new activity. What makes you think you need a new activity?

Comment: Actually Sir, I am new to Android, every where I get example of anything it is explained in Activity.

Comment: Like I get Activity Code(not fragment) here 
https://appsnipp.com/free-android-profile-design-with-source-code/

Comment: You should go through the [Navigation codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation) and watch the [Single Activity talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2k8x8V77CrU) for what you should be doing in 2020.

Comment: @HemantMaurya I was also wondering why you need an extra activity.

Comment: @ianhanniballake thank you for sharing the link. I will watch you :)

Comment: I think you are correct sir. I should go for single activity class.

Comment: Sir, Really Thank You :)