# Check if NavDestination represents a DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I have an Activity layout that surrounds the fragment container in a CoordinatorLayout. When switching destinations, I want to hide the FAB and dismiss the SnackBar if either is currently displayed, and let the destination Fragment reshow the FAB if it needs to in its `onViewCreated()`. This is consistent with the Material Design guidelines that say the FAB should visibly disappear and reappear when you switch destinations.

So I did this:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, navDestination, _ ->
    binding.floatingActionButton.apply {
        hide()
        setOnClickListener(null)
    }
    currentSnackbar?.dismiss()
    //...
}
```

However, when a DialogFragment is the navigation destination, the previous Fragment will not have `onViewCreated()` called again when navigating back, because it never left the screen.

NavDestination doesn't seem to have any way to inspect whether it represents a DialogFragment, even though the XML distinguishes between `fragment` and `dialog`.

I realize I could move the FAB showing code to `onResume` in the fragment, but it would look silly to hide it in the first place when only opening an alert dialog. I realize I could also create a parent Fragment class that hides it in `onStop()`, but I try to avoid creating class hierarchy layers when possible to make code less fragile (composition over inheritance), and I also want to avoid repeating the code all over the app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dialog destinations implement the [`FloatingWindow` interface](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/FloatingWindow):

> A marker interface for `NavDestination` subclasses that float above the view of other destinations (i.e. `DialogFragmentNavigator.Destination`).
>
> `NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener` instances can also customize their behavior based on whether the destination is a `FloatingWindow`.

Therefore you can ignore navigating to dialog by using `if (!(navDestination is FloatingWindow))`.

Comment: Note that you'll get another callback when you return to the previous (non-dialog) destination. You might consider using an [argument based listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57928305/1676363) for whether you should be showing the FAB on a particular destination and skipping any logic in `onViewCreated()` - that way you would know precisely whether the FAB should be hidden or not no matter what destination you navigate to.